# Application manifest for azure enterprise applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an enterprise application hosted with azure. Authentication page is refreshing again and again even after putting credentials and users are not able to log-in. I tried to resolve this issue by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/troubleshooting/auth/aadauth-enableimplicitoauth). But as my application is an enterprise application , I can not see any manifest file in azure portal. Can some expert help me to find and edit manifest file for enterprise application?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested in my tenant and can see the manifest for one of my enterprise applications. You need to do it from the App Registrations section.

Go to Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Select "All apps" from the dropdown > click into the enterprise application that you have registered under that tenant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marilee. But actually I do not see my application registered under app registrations. Is it necessary that all apps should be in app registrations?  Is it mandatory that every enterprise application should be registered under app registrations?

Comment: Yes you definitely need to register it if you want to edit the manifest or use Azure Active Directory. It's mandatory. The only case where it is not mandatory is if your app isn't using Azure Active Directory, doesn't have sign-in/sign-out capabilities, or you don't need to authenticate any users. (Even in that case, it wouldn't hurt to register it.)

Comment: You can just go to "App Registrations" and create a new one for that application.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation Marilee. We currently have many users registered in Enterprise application. Do we have to move all of them to newly created app in app registrations? Or these users need to register again under the new app? Can the old users directly log-in into our app using new auth-id or some changes are needed? Sorry for bothering too much , I am new to azure.

Comment: It's no bother. :) You can assign users by app, by group, or just assign them under the AAD tenant. You shouldn't need to re-assign them because if you already added them to the app, the app will still be the same. It won't be a new application - it will just be the same application but the registration will exist under your tenant. Here's a simple example I made with my colleague: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs&t=1s

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Enterprise application properties to see which Azure AD is the publisher for that application?

One possible reason could be that the application is Multi-tenant and the Azure AD that you're looking in is just a tenant using the application and not really the Azure AD that has published the application.

Application registration will exist only in the publishing Azure AD. (you can reach the manifest there, assuming you have appropriate permissions in the publishing Azure AD)

Enterprise Application > Properties (Notice the **Publisher**)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rohit. I am not admin I do not know who is the admin. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Are you not even able to see the enterprise application in your active directory through the Azure Portal? Look at the screenshot.. I am not showing the manifest, but just the properties under Enterprise application itself